# Run QEMU in virtualized UBUNTU via VMWARE

Tags: linux, windows, virtualization, vmware, qemu

I am using Windows host and I would like to run a Vmware workstation ubuntu client. In that client, I would like to run QEMU. The problem I am facing is I cannot turn on the virtual machine with `Virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT or AMD-V/RVI` option on:

[image]

[image]

I have the following settings checked in the Windows features panel:

[image]

I can as well disable them, but then the virtual machine itself wont turn on. What is the right approach to enable virtualization within virtualization? My host PC runs Windows 10 x64 on a Xenon W-11955M CPU.

Comment: Make sure Workstation means Workstation Pro. Then make sure the version you have supports nested VMs.  Even then I am not sure Workstation Pro will support nesting with QEMU.  I use Workstation Pro and have an Ubuntu 22.04 guest and  have not seen that.

Comment: With Hyper-V enabled you can't use VT-x/EPT in a VM with Workstation.  You need to disable Hyper-V to get access to the necessary CPU features.  This is a known "issue".  Various Windows security features can also cause this.  A quick google search for your error will give a lot of details.